# How do I compile + link C++ code in Xcode in an Objective-C project?

Tags: c++, ios, objective-c, xcode, objective-c++

I have an iOS project with lots of Obj-C sources and a few `.cpp` files.
There is one C++ class `CalibrationFileReader`, which I created in Xcode 6, which has a `.h` and a `.cpp` file. I can use that class from my Objective-C code.

I have a second pair of C++ files (`stereo_v3.hpp`, `stereo_v3.cpp`) which do not include a class, but only static functions. Those I added to the project from outside. When I try to use one of the functions  (`computePoseDifference`), it compiles fine but Xcode refuses to link, complaining

```
Undefined symbols for architecture arm64:
  "computePoseDifference(cv::Mat const&, cv::Mat const&, cv::Mat&, cv::Mat&, std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >)", referenced from:
```

Things I tried:

1. Creating the files in Xcode and pasting the original code in them
2. Manually add the `.cpp` file to *Compile Sources* in *Build Phases*  for my target (see image).
   [image]

Neither resolved the problem.

Comment: I use C++ in Xcode 6 frequently, and I run into similar linkage problems, although none of my calls have nearly so many parameters. What I do to find more info is to explicitly cast parameters to `const` where appropriate, which usually either fixes the linkage or gives me a message that a parameter cannot be cast to `const`.

Comment: @NathanOliver How is that related? That question is about libraries, not sources.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, turns out Xcode was not the culprit, but the `static` modifier I prefixed the function's declaration with. So the question was premature. I should've known, but of course, the static linkage makes them invisible for other translation units.